Invariants of quadratic space over finite field.
Assume $(V, Q)$ is a quadratic space of dimension $n$ over a field $F_q$ of odd characteristic, where $Q$ is a quadratic form.
Let $W \subseteq V$ be a subspace of $V$.
Let $w = (w_1, w_2, \dots, w_n)$ and $w' = (w'_1, w'_2, \dots, w'_n)$ be two orthogonal bases of $W$.
Is it true that
$$
\mu( Q(w_1) Q(w_2) \cdots  Q(w_n) ) = \mu( Q(w'_1) Q(w'_2) \cdots  Q(w'_n) ),  
$$
where $\mu$ is the quadratic character ($\mu(x) = 1$ if $x$ is a square in $F_q$ and $-1$ otherwise)?
This question arises from Proposition 9.1 (page 75) in Larry C. Grove "Classical Groups and Geometric Algebra".

I believe I have successfully proven the required statement, but I am not entirely clear on the proof of the proposition itself. Here is my reasoning:
If $w = (w_1, w_2, \dots, w_n)$ is an orthogonal basis, then
$$
\sigma_w(x) = \sigma_{w_1}\sigma_{w_2}\cdots\sigma_{w_n}(x) = x - 2\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{B(x,w_i)}{Q(w_i)}w_i.  
$$
If $x = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \alpha_i w_i$, then
$$
\sigma_w(x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \alpha_i w_i - 2\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{\alpha_i Q(w_i)}{Q(w_i)}w_i = -x.  
$$
Similarly, $\sigma_{w'} = -1|_W$.
Hence, $\sigma_{w}\sigma_{w'} = 1|_W$, and from the proposition,
$$
\mu( Q(w_1) Q(w_2) \cdots  Q(w_n) Q(w'_1) Q(w'_2) \cdots  Q(w'_n)) = 1.  
$$
My questions are as follows:

Are there any sources where the proof of Proposition 9.1 is explained in more detail?
Is my application of this proposition correct?
Is it possible to calculate this invariant for the case when $W = \langle v_1, v_2, \dots, v_s \rangle^\perp$ in a general form, without explicitly computing the basis?


Well, Lam (2005) Introduction to Quadratic Forms over Fields   does this,similar modern language, especially Proposition 1.12 on page 108.

I like Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms. Chapter 10 is The Spin and Orthogonal Groups.

and Cassels recommends Scharlau (1969)   Quadratic Forms, about 162 pages. Not sure I've ever seen that one. On page 191 Cassels says "For Clifford Algebras, see also Lam(1973) and Scharlau (1969)."  I have seen Scharlau's 1985 book in English

I will give an alternative proof for your claim, and then use that methodology to answer (3).
WLOG we, for the moment, assume $W=V$.
The elements of the Clifford algebra $Cl(Q)$ associated to $Q$ can be canonically identified with the elements of the exterior algebra of $V$. In particular, since $w_1,\dotsc,w_n$ and $w_1',\dotsc,w_n'$ are orthogonal we have that the Clifford products $I=w_1\dotsb w_n$ and $J=w_1'\dotsb w_n'$ are (nonzero) elements of ${\bigwedge}^nV$. Since $n=\dim V$ there is a nonzero scalar $\alpha$ such that $I=\alpha J$. But
$$
  Q(w_1)\dotsb Q(w_n) = \widetilde II
$$
and similarly for $J$, where $I\mapsto\widetilde I=w_n\dotsb w_1$ is the main antiautomorphism (also known as reversal). Now $\widetilde II=\alpha^2\widetilde JJ$, so $\widetilde II$ and $\widetilde JJ$ belong to the same square class, QED. (In fact, a stronger result than just having the same $\mu$.)

When $W\ne V$ nothing changes; now $I,J$ are simple elements of ${\bigwedge}^nV$ such that $$[I] = W = [J]$$ where $$[I] := \{v\in V\;:\;v\wedge I=0\}$$ and the same argument goes through. Choose any nonzero $K\in{\bigwedge}^{\dim V}V$. Then $IK\in{\bigwedge}^{\dim V-n}V$ is simple and $W^\perp=[IK]$. So all we want is the square class of
$$
  \widetilde{IK}IK = (\widetilde II)(\widetilde KK)
$$
So clearly we have
$$
  s(W^\perp) = s(W)s(V)
$$
where $s(W)\in F^\times/F^{\times2}$ is the square class of $\widetilde II=Q(w_1)\dotsb Q(w_n)$. From this we conclude
$$
  \mu(W^\perp) = \begin{cases}
    1 &\text{if }s(W)=s(V),\\
   -1 &\text{otherwise},
  \end{cases}
$$
where of course $\mu(W) := \mu(Q(w_1)\dotsb Q(w_n))$.

This implicitly assumes that $W$ and $V$ are nondegenerate. However, $\mu(W)$ makes no sense when $W$ is degenerate, and $W^\perp$ is degenerate if either $W$ or $V$ is, so the question is moot.
